# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean CheckMeetingSettings(Int64, Int64)' method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I am working with code first approach in EDM and facing an error for which I can't the solution.Pls help me

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   CheckMeetingSettings(Int64, Int64)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

My code is following(this is the query which I have written

```
from per in obj.tempPersonConferenceDbSet
           where per.Conference.Id == 2
           select new PersonDetials
           {
               Id = per.Person.Id,
               JobTitle = per.Person.JobTitle,
               CanSendMeetingRequest = CheckMeetingSettings(6327,per.Person.Id)
           }

public bool CheckMeetingSettings(int,int)
{
  ///code I have written.
}
```

Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 3):

EF can not convert custom code to SQL. Try iterating the result set and assigning the property outside the LINQ query.

```
var people = (from per in obj.tempPersonConferenceDbSet
           where per.Conference.Id == 2
           order by /**/
           select new PersonDetials
           {
               Id = per.Person.Id,
               JobTitle = per.Person.JobTitle,
           }).Skip(/*records count to skip*/)
             .Take(/*records count to retrieve*/)
             .ToList();

people.ForEach(p => p.CanSendMeetingRequest = CheckMeetingSettings(6327, p.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I need paging too in this.In my database I have over 1 lac users.Pls give with paging...

Comment: @user1314655 Use the `Skip` and `Take` methods to paginate. You also need to sort the query with `order by`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Entities can't translate your custom code into a SQL query.

You might consider first selecting only the database columns, then add a .ToList() to force the query to resolve. After you have those results you van do another select where you add the information from your CheckMeetingSettings method.

I'm more comfortable with the fluid syntax so I've used that in the following example.

```
var query = obj.tempPersonConferenceDbSet
               .Where(per => per.Conference.Id == 2).Select(per => new { Id = per.Person.Id, JobTitle = per.Person.JobTitle })
               .ToList()
               .Select(per => new PersonDetails { Id = per.Id, 
                                                  JobTitle = per.JobTitle,
                                                  CanSendMeetingRequest = CheckMeetingSettings(6327, per.Person.Id) })
```

If your CheckMeetingSettings method also accesses the database you might want to consider not using a seperate method to prevent a SELECT N+1 scenario and try to express the logic as part of the query in terms that the database can understand.

Comment: Thanks it is working but consuming lot of time to execute the query.Can we have another approach to get it done quickly.Pls assist me

Answer (score 1):

With Entity Framework, you cannot mix code that runs on the database server with code that runs inside the application. The only way you could write a query like this, is if you defined a function inside SQL Server to implement the code that you've written.

More information on how to expose that function to LINQ to Entities can be found [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/28/entity-sql-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Alternatively, you would have to call `CheckMeetingSettings` outside the initial query, as Eranga demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will follow it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var personDetails = obj.tempPersonConferenceDbSet.Where(p=>p.ConferenceId == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(p=> new PersonDetials
           {
               Id = per.Person.Id,
               JobTitle = per.Person.JobTitle,
               CanSendMeetingRequest = CheckMeetingSettings(6327,per.Person.Id)
           });

public bool CheckMeetingSettings(int,int)
{
  ///code I have written.
}
```

You must use `AsEnumerable()` so you can preform `CheckMeetingSettings`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.when I am using this code I have struck with some other error i.e.,  {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}